# How to make my calculator app accept float values in C?

Tags: c

I made a basic calculator in C but it only accept integer values and I want to program to accept float values. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int mod;
        printf("Enter function 1:Add 2:Subtract 3:Multiply 4:Divide : ");
        scanf("%d",&mod);
        printf("Enter first number: ");
        scanf("%d",&num1);
        printf("Enter second number: ");
        scanf("%d",&num2);
        if(mod == 1) {
                printf("Answer is %d\n",num1+num2);
        }
        if(mod == 2) {
                printf("Answer is %d\n",num1-num2);
        }
        if(mod == 3) {
                printf("Answer is %d\n",num1*num2);
        }
        if(mod == 4) {
                printf("Answer is %d\n",num1/num2);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I want my program to accept float input.

Comment: `scanf` without checking return value -> bad things about to happen, you don't know if you've actually matched any input, your variables may be uninitalized. Aside from that, [check the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: It will accept floating point values if you use floating point (`double`) variables instead of `int` variables.

Comment: I would start by changing `int` to `float` or `double` and `%d` to `%f`...

Answer (score 2):

So, to answer your question briefly, you're using "int" instead of "float" for the operands. You need to declare them as "float" instead of "int" and actually given the speed of modern processors, their 64-bit architecture, and the cheapness of memory today, you're better off using a "double" for each instead of "float".

But this still won't actually work. Why not? Because your format strings in `scanf` are `"%d"`. This means it will parse the user input string as an integer and then store that integer - sans decimal and everything following - in the integer, float, or double that you pass to `scanf`. In order to store a single precision floating point value, your variables will have to be of type `float` and your scanf will have to use the format string `"%f"`. For a double precision floating point, you would need to declare them as `double` and use the format string `"lf"`. "lf" stands for "long float".

### Example of scanning into doubles using your code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> /* I don't see you using any math functions though */
#include <stdlib.h> /* needed for exit() */

int main()
{
    double num1;
    double num2;

    int mod; /* this can remain an int because it is a menu choice */

    /* You can see below that I put something around your scanf calls.
     * These are error checks that the calls do not fail to produce a
     * value to use inside the pointer. */
    
    printf("Enter function 1:Add 2:Subtract 3:Multiply 4:Divide : ");
    if (scanf("%d",&mod) != 1) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, invalid input"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    printf("Enter first number: ");
    if (scanf("%lf",&num1) != 1) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, invalid input"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    printf("Enter second number: ");
    if (scanf("%lf",&num2) != 1) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, invalid input"); 
        exit(1); 
    }

    /* The rest of the code is correct except that if you use 
     * this code above, you'll want to use `"%lf"` in your
     * printf statements for outputting the result. */

}
```

Comment: I understand that I should check the variables.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `int num1; int num2;` to `float num1; float num2;` and `%d` to `%f` and it worked.New Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
        float num1;
        float num2;
        int mod;
        printf("Enter function 1:Add 2:Subtract 3:Multiply 4:Divide : ");
        scanf("%d",&mod);
        printf("Enter first number: ");
        scanf("%f",&num1);
        printf("Enter second number: ");
        scanf("%f",&num2);
        if(mod == 1) {
                printf("Answer is %f\n",num1+num2);
        }
        if(mod == 2) {
                printf("Answer is %f\n",num1-num2);
        }
        if(mod == 3) {
                printf("Answer is %f\n",num1*num2);
        }
        if(mod == 4) {
                printf("Answer is %f\n",num1/num2);
        }

        return 0;
}
```